# Zxing, call in Fragment and get Result

Tags: android, fragment, zxing

I have the following problem: I´m trying to launch my scanner from an fragment. But actually it´s not possible to catch the result via onActivityResult in this fragment.

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v){


    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());

    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setCaptureActivity(HorizontalActivity.class);
    integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
    integrator.initiateScan();


}
```

I also tried the code from the example

```
IntentIntegrator.forFragment(getActivity())
```

But my problem is that I am using the .v4.App.FragmentActivity and the Konstruktor is only for App.Fragment.

Maybe you could help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this inside your fragment....

```
IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this).initiateScan();
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result != null) {
            if(result.getContents() == null) {
               //Cancelled
            } else {
               //"Scanned Result=" + result.getContents()
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, its could be called either from activity or fragment.

```
fun scanQrCode() {
    var intent = Intent(activity, ScanQrActivity::class.java)
    intent.setAction(Intents.Scan.ACTION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)

    intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.PROMPT_MESSAGE, "Scan unit id")
    intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.CAMERA_ID, 0)
    intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.BEEP_ENABLED, true)
    intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.BARCODE_IMAGE_ENABLED, false)
    this.startActivityForResult(intent, 1111)

}
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

    if (requestCode.equals(1111)) {
        val contents = data?.getStringExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT)
        if (contents == null)
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, contents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```